# Integrate function by partial derivative

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, numerical-methods

I'm searching a $\phi(x,t)$ solution of a pde cauchy system, with $x\in[-1,1],t\in[0,T]$

I am able to know:

a) $\phi(x,0)=-cos\left(\pi\left(x-0.85\right)\right)$

b) $\phi_x(x,t)$, $\forall t,x$ (by numerical approximation)

How can I calculate $\phi(x,t)?$

I tried $\phi(x,t)=\int_{-1}^{x}\phi(s,t)ds$ but it's not good...

Answer (score 0):

Let $\phi$ be a solution to the problem

$$\left\{ \begin{eqnarray} \frac {\partial \phi} {\partial x} (x,t) &=& \psi (x,t) \\
\phi (x,0) &=& - \cos \big( \pi (x - 0.85) \big) , \end{eqnarray} \right.$$

where $\psi$ is a function considered known (obtained, for instance, by experimental measurements). Notice, then, that if $c : [0,T] \to \Bbb R$ is any smooth function with $c(0) = 0$, the new function $(x,t) \mapsto \phi (x,t) + c(t)$ satisfies exactly the same problem. Therefore, all the solutions will be of the form $\phi = \phi _0 + c$, with $\phi_0$ some particular solution and $c$ a function (of $t$) as above.

For the particular solution you may consider, for instance, $\phi_0 (x,t) = \int \limits _{-1} ^x \psi (y,t) \ \Bbb d t$.

This means that, unless you are able to impose further constraints (of physical nature, for instance) on your problem, it will have too many solutions.

The reason for this is that your equation, being of the 1st order in $x$, is an evolution equation in $x$, so for uniqueness it would need an "initial" state for some fixed $x$. The condition that you give, though, is given for a fixed value of $t$, not of $x$.

Comment: did what you suggest and it's almost perfect, only one issue: my $\phi(x,t)$ do a vertical shift. it seems like I calculate $\xi(x,t)=\phi(x,t)+k(t)$ with k>0 (for t=0 it's perfect) @Alex M.

Comment: @Bombadil: I have reconsidered my answer, the previous version was wrong.

Comment: maybe something like periodically boundary condition? @Alex M.

Comment: @Bombadil: I don't quite get that: periodicity makes sense when one of the variables lives in an interval of infinite length, which is not the case here. No, what you need is one thing: an $x_0 \in [-1,1]$ for which $\phi (x_0, t)$ is known for all $t$. Otherwise, you cannot fix the function $c$ from my answer. Alternatively, but more complicately, adding an equation of the type $\frac {\partial \phi} {\partial t} = \chi$ would again help obtain uniqueness (because it would give a 1st order differential equation for $c$, and you already have the corresponding initial condition $c(0) = 0$).

Comment: My original problem is (in $[-1,1]\times [0,T]$)

$\begin{cases}\phi_t+H(\phi_x) = 0\\\phi(x,0)=-cos(\pi(x-0.85)) & \end{cases}$ , $H(v)=\frac{(v+1)^2}{2}$

with periodic boundary conditions, so i thinked that solution... @Alex M.

Comment: @Bombadil: Well, this changes everything. If $\phi_x$ is considered known (is it?), then $H(\phi_x)$ will also be known, so the equation is $\phi_t = \psi$: notice that the derivative is with respect to $t$, not to $x$ (as you wrote in your post). So, which of the two versions is the correct one?

Comment: Doing $v=\phi_x+1$ and $f(v)=H(v-1)$ I can find $\phi_x$ as solution of

\begin{cases}u_t+f(u)_x=0 \\u(x,0)=\pi \sin(\pi(x-0.85))\end{cases}

so I have

\begin{cases}u_t+u u_x=0 \\u(x,0)=\pi \sin(\pi(x-0.85))\end{cases}

and with method of caratheristics

$u(\overline{x},\overline{t})=\pi\sin(\pi(y-0.85))$ with $y$ root of 

$\overline{x}=y+\overline{t}\left[ \pi\sin\left(\pi(y-0.85)\right)\right]$

finally $\phi_x(x,t)=u(x,t)-1$ so I know $\phi(x,t)$  @Alex M.